# Replacing empty datetime cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

My original (Excel) table looks like this:

```
Code     StartDate       EndDate      Value
900                   31.12.9999       80.9
901                   31.12.9999       98.8
902                   13.02.2020       98.3
903                   10.01.2007       90.6
903                   31.12.9999       90.7
904      09.04.2020   31.12.9999       98.9
905                   12.02.2009       87.6
905                   13.04.2011       78.0
905                   31.12.9999       89.5
```

The start date is mostly empty. I want to fill in the empty values the following way:

- if `Code` is unique, `StartDate` is 01.01.2000.
- if `Code` is not unique, `StartDate` is 01.01.2000 for the first appearance and then the next day after the last `EndDate`.

So it would be:

```
Code       StartDate       EndDate      Value
900       01.01.2000    31.12.9999       80.9
901       01.01.2000    31.12.9999       98.8
902       01.01.2000    13.02.2020       98.3
903       01.01.2000    10.01.2007       90.6
903       11.01.2007    31.12.9999       90.7
904       09.04.2020    31.12.9999       98.9
905       01.01.2000    12.02.2009       87.6
905       13.02.2009    13.04.2011       78.0
905       14.04.2011    31.12.9999       89.5
```

My problem is that in pandas the `StartDate` is read in a format like `2010-09-06` (which I am very okay with), but the `EndDate` appears as `9999-12-31 00:00:00` and converting it is tricky because of the year limit (all the methods involving this problem were leading to deleting such a record, which I do not want). I left it like that but I do not know how to go further with the replacement.

Is there any way to fill in such empty shells in pandas?

Comment: Maybe this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: @pinegulf thank you, I looked into it but I still have the problem of that 9999 year and the fact that I fill them in based on different conditions.

Comment: `StartDate` is filled by empty string or nan?

Comment: @Corralien right now it is filled by NaT.

Comment: do you want +1day or +1month?

Comment: @mozway sorry, one day!

Comment: @mozway but it is DD.MM.YYYY format.

Comment: OK, I'll fix the data but the general logic in my answer should work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yet, on the general principle you could use a `groupby`+`shift` and add `pd.Timedelta('1d')` to get the next date per group, the use `fillna` twice to replace the missing dates:

```
# pre-requisite using datetime type
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

df['StartDate'] = (df['StartDate']
                     .fillna(df['EndDate']
                               .groupby(df['Code'])
                               .shift()+pd.Timedelta('1d')
                            )
                     .fillna('01.01.2000')
                  )
```

*NB. I change the years 9999 to 2099 as 9999 is too high for pandas. Also I assumed the empty cells are `NaT`.*

output:

```
   Code  StartDate    EndDate  Value
0   900 2000-01-01 2099-12-31   80.9
1   901 2000-01-01 2099-12-31   98.8
2   902 2000-01-01 2020-02-13   98.3
3   903 2000-01-01 2007-01-10   90.6
4   903 2007-01-11 2099-12-31   90.7
5   904 2020-04-09 2099-12-31   98.9
6   905 2000-01-01 2009-02-12   87.6
7   905 2009-02-13 2011-04-13   78.0
8   905 2011-04-14 2099-12-31   89.5
```